# Flea on infinite chessboard jumping with irrational vector eventually changes square color

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

*Question from Engel's Problem Solving Strategies:*

> An infinite chessboard consists of $1 \times 1$ squares. A flea starts on a white square and makes jumps by $\alpha$ to the right and $\beta$ upwards, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real numbers such that the ratio $\alpha / \beta$ is irrational (So the flea jumps diagonally). Prove that sooner or later it will reach a black square.

WLOG suppose that the flea starts at $(0,0)$. So the flea steps on the coordinates $(k\alpha, k\beta)$, for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. I need to show that eventually $\lfloor{k\alpha}\rfloor + \lfloor{k \beta}\rfloor$ is an even number.

So I must show that $\lfloor{k\alpha}\rfloor$ and $\lfloor{k \beta}\rfloor$ must eventually have the same parity. Intuitively I know there must exist some $k$ such that $\lfloor k\alpha \rfloor$ and $\lfloor (k+1) \alpha \rfloor$ have same parity, while $\lfloor k\beta \rfloor$ and $\lfloor (k+1)\beta \rfloor$ have different parity.

How do I do this?

Comment: What you mean by $\alpha/\beta$ irrational?

Comment: i have edited for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure about the coordinate system you're using. If your $(0,0)$ is meant to be the bottom left corner of the first white square, then since it's on the corner, it's also on the boundary, so it could in theory be considered to be any of the $4$ squares at that corner.

To avoid any such issues, I will define the coordinates & starting point I'll be using this way. The $S_{a,\ b}$ square, for $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$, is defined by $a \lt x \lt a + 1$ and $b \lt y \lt b + 1$. I assume the $S_{0,\ 0}$ square is white. Then the white squares are $S_{a,\ b}$ where $a$ & $b$ have the same parity and the black squares are $S_{a,\ b}$ where $a$ & $b$ have opposite parities.

Assume the flea starts in the middle of the $S_{0,\ 0}$ white square, i.e., at coordinates $(0.5,0.5)$. Let

$$\alpha = 2 - r \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

$$\beta = r \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

where $0 \lt r \lt 1$ is an irrational number. Then $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\frac{\alpha}{\beta} = \frac{2}{r} - 1$ are all irrational. After $k$ jumps, the flea will be at $(0.5 + k\alpha,0.5 + k\beta)$. Since both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are irrationals, neither $0.5 + k\alpha$ or $0.5 + k\beta$ can be integers, so there's no concern about landing on a border. To land on a black square requires that $\lfloor 0.5 + k\alpha \rfloor + \lfloor 0.5 + k\beta \rfloor$ be an odd integer since the $2$ integer terms must have opposite parities. Let

$$kr = 0.5 + n + s \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $0 \lt s \lt 1$. Using \eqref{eq1}, \eqref{eq2} and \eqref{eq3} gives

\begin{align}
\lfloor 0.5 + k\alpha \rfloor & = \lfloor 0.5 + 2k - kr \rfloor \\
& = \lfloor 2k - n - s \rfloor \\
& = 2k - n - 1 \tag{4}\label{eq4}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\lfloor 0.5 + k\beta \rfloor & = \lfloor 1 + n + s \rfloor \\
& = n + 1 \tag{5}\label{eq5}
\end{align}

Using \eqref{eq4} and \eqref{eq5} gives

$$\lfloor 0.5 + k\alpha \rfloor + \lfloor 0.5 + k\beta \rfloor = 2k \tag{6}\label{eq6}$$

As such, this is always an even integer and, thus, it'll never be situated on a black square.

Note you can also use your original $(0,0)$, if you define that corner to be for the square to its right & up, by dropping the $0.5$ part from \eqref{eq3} to get the same result.

It seems that either the OP or myself has made a mistake or has a misunderstanding here, the Engel's Problem Solving Strategies question is not correct, or there's some other unstated condition.

Comment: I have added the original question as well! I suppose it is possible that the author intended it to mean the flea either jumps straight upwards or to the right, but not diagonally.

Comment: @eatfood I appreciate you adding the original question text. Your text said they jumped diagonally but I believe, as your comment above indicates, the flea either jumps to the right by $\alpha$ or up by $\beta$. I suspect the question requires the flea to always alternate (but I'm not sure if this is always true) as, otherwise, you can just show the flea will always land on a black square eventually by just strictly going up or to the right. It's getting late for me, but I'll think about this & see if I can come up with a solution to this new version sometime later.

Comment: I think since you have proved that under my first intepretation, the statement is false, then I think the author probably meant the 2nd interpretation. Thank you!

Comment: For the second interpretation, I think since the flea jumps forever, there is one direction (up or right) that the flea takes infinitely many times. Suppose that direction is up. Then maybe it can be argued that the occasional rightwards jump won't disrupt the fact that the flea will eventually be forced to land on a black square on one of its upwards jumps.

Comment: @eatfood In my opinion, the question is ambiguous & poorly worded. I'm still not sure what was intended. Requiring $\alpha/\beta$ be irrational only makes sense, I believe, if you're dealing with moving along a diagonal. As such, I would've likely interpreted it as you did initially. If so, though, they have a mistake in their proof. Otherwise, whether forced to always alternate or if can choose whether to jump right or up, the flea will always eventually land on a black square. This is because for each jump, only the $x$ or $y$ coordinate changes. All you need to show is that the parity ...

Comment: @eatfood of it will eventually change. I'm quite certain this can be shown to always occur eventually for the multiples of any irrational number, but if you're interested, you should try to prove it yourself.

Comment: Your point about the condition on $\alpha / \beta$ being irrational is a good one! As for the 2nd interpretation, after some thought I am quite convinced that the flea will change color, so I guess that resolves this question. Thanks!